# Why does Mac OS X turn off monitor #2 when an application is maximized on monitor #1?

Tags: macos, display

I am running OS X Yosemite 10.10.5 on a Mac Mini system with two monitors. When I maximize an application on monitor 'A', monitor 'B' then goes black while that application maximizes to fill 'A'.

Why the heck is this happening? How do I fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why?
Personally,. because I don't think they ever thought it through properly. There's a lot about fullscreen that's like that.

The fix is possibly System Prefs > Mission Control > check Displays have separate Spaces

[image]

The better fix is don't use fullscreen, use Alt/click on the green button to maximise instead.

Comment: Thank you! This may sound silly, but you have made my night. Now my code development may exist peacefully now, with Firefox open... ;)!!!!!

Comment: Nothing silly about having a comfortable workflow :-) I'm a big Spaces user myself - but fullscreen really messes Spaces up. See http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/179376/what-is-an-efficient-way-for-developers-power-users-to-use-osx-window-manageme/179403#179403 for some of my other ramblings on the subject ;)

Comment: I believe OS X El Capitan will be changing some of this.

Comment: I hope so, but I'm going to wait for the .1 release to see if it fixes some other things I found even more irritating in the GM ;)

Comment: Alt-click is a lifesaver! I disabled separate spaces so open applications can span multiple monitors. But the unexpected side-effect was that non-focused screens go black when you maximize an application. As a long-time Windows user the default behavior was confusing.