# Why can I not hide all the apps on my mac?

Tags: macos

this may be a repetitive question, but I was unable to find an exact solution anywhere.

I would really like to be able to hide *all* of the open applications on my mac without minimizing.  I have this workflow in mind:  Hide apps which I want to keep updated, minimize apps I am actually using but need to hide temporarily.

I just don't understand why we are restricted to minimizing the final app and not hiding it?  Does anyone know how to get around this?

Thank You

Comment: It might be simpler to get used to using Spaces instead of hide/show/hide/show every time. See some of my ramblings on Spaces here - http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/179376/what-is-an-efficient-way-for-developers-power-users-to-use-osx-window-manageme/179403#179403 & there are many more if you have a specific concern.  btw, you can hide any current frontmost app by alt/clicking the desktop.

Comment: Thanks @Tetsujin, I appreciate the advice.  I guess I never really noticed, but even when I am able to hide all windows (which seems to be possible in some strange instances where Cmd-H even hides the final window) the Finder still remains open.  I suppose Apple made their OS such that at least one app must always be open.  Is this true?

Comment: @Veita when hiding, at least one window must be visible.