# Automate Fn key switch between finder and photoshop?

Tags: software-recommendation, macos, automation

I would like to know if there any script that i can use to switch automatically between finder and photoshop?

I can't install Palua App from my AppStore on El-capitan.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Spaces.
Lock each app to its own space then use the built-in system hot keys to switch between those Spaces.

See my answer at https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/179403/85275 for some working methods.

Answer (score 0):

I would try making your shortcuts with Fast Scripts - it's free for 10 shortcuts or less.

- https://red-sweater.com/fastscripts/