# How to disable spaces?

Tags: macos, dock, spaces, mission-control

There is only one thing I hate on macOS (Sierra) since this was created.

I open an application and work on it.

I click on another application on the dock and the whole screen slides to the right and I see that app.

I click on the first application on the dock and the whole screen slides to the left.

For heaven's sake. How do I disable this? If I want to slide I go to an ice rink.

I have already typed that on terminal and restarted the machine

```
defaults write com.apple.dock mcx-expose-disabled -bool true
```

and this hateful thing continues.

I want to disable spaces, mission control and for that matter launchpad too and all other things like that.

Comment: If you want to disable Spaces, you also have to stop using fullscreen. Every fullscreen app gets its own Space.

Comment: add that to my list: disable full screen apps. I hate them too. I never use them.

Comment: OK, then if you don't use fullscreen you don't need to map apps to Spaces. Problem solved. Work in one Space, everything piled on top of everything else. Spaces don't populate themselves, you have to have done it.

Comment: I guarantee you I am not mapping anything to any space. MacOS is doing that alone.

Comment: Nope. It won't do that.

Comment: say that to my computer.

Comment: Unfortunately @Tetsujin, you have not made yourself clear with this answer & comments, just as you have not communicated clearly on the the 4 other places you've essentially given the same unhelpful answers. Not everyone is a pro level user. Please quit assuming (a) that people are asking about Fullscreen apps. You have made that wrong assumption every time and the user replies "that's not what I'm using". (b) The intent of this site is clear. Provide valid and useful answers or please don't answer people's questions about Spaces. Thank you.

Comment: @UXdesigner - it's not an answer, it's a comment. If you see the question this is marked a duplicate of, you'll see how this [used to] happen. afaik, it's a bug that has long been fixed. If you want to know more about Spaces, see https://superuser.com/a/1187552/347380 and https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/179403/85275

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have multiple spaces, you can delete them by exposing the Spaces (by default, Control-Up arrow), and then hover over one of the spaces with your mouse pointer. After a moment, you should see a round (X) appear in the upper left corner. Click and it will delete the space, repeat until you have only one left.

If you find that when you launch an app a space comes back, right-click on the App's icon in the dock, and look under the "Options >" menu. There may be a checkmark beside "This desktop." If so, selecting "None" and then closing the Space like before should stop that.

Edited based on comments: Mission Control does need to be re-enabled first. In the terminal, type

```
defaults delete com.apple.dock mcx-expose-disabled
```

and then

```
killall Dock
```

And wait for the dock to reload. Then, clear the unwanted spaces (or all of them!) and re-disable Mission Control.

Comment: these shortcuts do nothing for me.

Comment: Check in System Preferences->Mission Control, and look for the "Mission Control" keyboard shortcut, there may not be one assigned. You can assign one temporarily and use it to clear out the Spaces, then unassign it.

Comment: You may need to re-enable mission control first. Do: 
    defaults delete com.apple.dock mcx-expose-disabled 
and restart the Dock, then go in and delete the spaces, and then disable it again.

Comment: For fu*k's sake, deleting the key did mission control appear back and then I saw I had 32 spaces that I never created. I deleted all them and turned mission control off again. Now I am happy. THANKS!

Comment: Absolutely :-) Glad I could help!