# Vertical and horizontal workspace switching

Tags: macos

Mac has horizontal workspace switching, which is great. However, I find it very useful to have a 2D workspace grid (which I am used to from Linux) and I can switch both horizontally and vertically. Is there a way to do the same in Mac?

Comment: It used to be possible, but not any more since Mission Control. However, if you just consider the Spaces as 'numbers' rather than 'locations' then you can go straight to any number you like by key command. See https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/179403/85275 for some possible ideas.

Comment: this would be great

Comment: Is there third-party software for macOS that can do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not really. The Apple window managers work side to side for space switching on both iOS and macOS. Same with the split screen control - only side to side movement is programmed.

You could get an alternative window manager, but you can probably get 90% of the benefit learning the key shortcuts to move quickly to a set screen and disabling the "reorder spaces" option in Mission control.

I get why that's there for new users, but power users almost never want their spaces to be "reorganized" on the fly.

Comment: Also, enabling the hotkey shortcuts for moving between workspaces, noted [in the first comment to OP](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/300800/vertical-and-horizontal-workspace-switching#comment380056_300800), is a huge help. `Sys Prefs > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Mission Control`, and check the relevants option(s). FTW.