# Mission Control in a 2D arrangement?

Tags: mission-control

Is there a way of arranging Mission Control's workspaces in a two dimensional layout (like 5x5)?

So far I've only been able to arrange them in a one dimensional straight line (like 1x9) across the top.  I'm finding that even though there are fewer workspaces, I get "lost" more often with 1x9 than 5x5.

Thanks.

Comment: This is how the predecessor to Mission Control worked. I don't know of any native way to do it these days. One trick is to learn the Space numbers - have a look at https://superuser.com/a/1187552/347380 and https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/179403/85275 for some working methods.

Comment: It looks like this question has been asked previously: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/300800/vertical-and-horizontal-workspace-switching