# Annoying behavior when showing desktop

Tags: mojave, shortcut

I use the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>F3</kbd> to scatter the windows and show my Desktop, and then unzip an archive on the Desktop. After unzipping, the windows always scatter back automatically.

Then I have to use <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>F3</kbd> again to show Desktop again, so I can interact with the unzipped directory.

[image]

Does anyone know how to stop this? It's super annoying.

Comment: It appears to be the default behavior and probably cannot be changed.

Comment: Keep Finder on Space 1 & put other apps on other Spaces. That way you don't have to go digging for things all the time. See https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/179403/85275 for an objective lesson in Spaces.