# Stop hiding minimised windows on Mac?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, high-sierra

I multitask a lot, have a lot of windows open at the same time, even though I'm mostly peeking at using around 2 of them. I've become a fan of the alt+tab shortcut.

I love that the window goes to the dock on minimize, but is there a way I can stop mac putting them into the dock, or better yet blocking access to minimized applications on the alt+tab shortcut?

Comment: Use Spaces instead.  See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/179376/what-is-an-efficient-way-for-developers-power-users-to-use-osx-window-manageme for some ideas

Comment: You don't say whether you have multiple windows open in each app. If you don't, you could consider Hide (Cmd-H) rather than Minimize. This will instantly hide all windows associated with an app, and they won't be added to the dock. However, the app will still appear in the Cmd-Tab chain.