# Is there a keyboard shortcut on Mac, which accesses a specific running app on Dock?

Tags: macos, keyboard, shortcut, pc

On PC, I could open easily do that by pressing `WINDOW + NUMBER`.

`Win + (NUMBER 1-9)` [Open the desktop and start the app pinned to the taskbar in the position indicated by the number.]

Comment: It can't be done as written, but Spaces is a very powerful structure, which you may find you even prefer, as you can 'lock' it so the same key is always the same Space & same apps etc - see https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/179376/what-is-an-efficient-way-for-developers-power-users-to-use-osx-window-manageme/179403#179403 for some tips.

Comment: The Mac way of switching between *running* apps is command-tab and as I recall, there is (or used to be) a way of controlling the order (though I’m not sure if that would fit your description precisely, especially since it doesn’t map to a number).  However, you can create a keyboard shortcut to select a specific app in the Apple->Recent Items menu. You could make the shortcuts correspond to dock position if you want. And of course, if you wanted something more general, you could apple-script it or create an Automator workflow.