# Automatically put maximized window to first workspace

Tags: macos, window-manager, spaces

is there any way to automatically put maximized window to first workspace instead of last? I'd rather use it that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume you mean fullscreen?

Maximising will fill the current Space. Fullscreen will always go to the right of all existing Spaces. There's no way to change that.

Personally, I never use fullscreen because of that behaviour [amongst others]
Fullscreen apps cannot be on numbered, instantly-recallable Spaces, which just breaks any chance of having a sensible workflow.

Have a look at [What is an efficient way for developers / power users to use OSX window management and Spaces on a single screen?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/179376/what-is-an-efficient-way-for-developers-power-users-to-use-osx-window-manageme) for an alternative working method.

Comment: Great answer- remember to vote up questions worth the time for an answer.