# Create/switch between workspaces

Tags: settings, mission-control, switching

I am currently working on multiple projects where I use multiple desktops (created by the "+" button in mission control) and full screens (when entering full screen mode in an application (cmd + ctrl + f)).

Now, when I work on multiple projects the amount of windows used simultaneously is rather confusing which is why I often close all tasks/windows associated with one project to get a clear workspace for the other project.

I was wondering if there is a possibility where I can save the currently open windows and workspace settings, such that by a simple click I can switch between multiple workspaces. Let's say you work on a coding project where you use multiple files as references, an IDE, a browser with multiple tabs/windows open, etc. Now, you'd like to switch (temporarily close all open applications) to another coding project which requires a completely different setting, but in no way less extensive. Instead of opening the IDE and all associated windows and files manually, one could open all of them automatically (a setting saved from the last time you worked on that project).

I never heard of something like this which is why I hoped someone of the community might have an idea.

Comment: I don't think it's possible - but see https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/179376/what-is-an-efficient-way-for-developers-power-users-to-use-osx-window-manageme for some working practices [one of which is to avoid using fullscreen, as it's uncontrollable]

Comment: Or create several user accounts (one per project) and set file/Access permissions as required. It still will be a hassle to switch though