# Is there a keyboard shortcut to allow me to go back to my last used space?

Tags: spaces

Suppose I have 10 spaces and I am currently using Space 1. Often times I'll <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> to an app in macOS and it will take me to where that app is (lets say it takes me to Space 10).

Is there a keyboard shortcut that I can use to take me back to Space 1? I find it annoying I have to <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>Left Arrow</kbd> so many times to get back to Space 1 from Space 10.

If not, is it possible to write a Hammerspoon script to mimic this behaviour?

Ideally the proposed solution should work on macOS 10.15 Catalina (the OS I'm currently using).

Comment: See https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/179403/85275 I never use Cmd/Tab, always just the key command to the Space I need.