# Customize title bar color of application windows

Tags: software-recommendation, window-manager, color, expose

I'm a software developer and my daily work involves about 8 or 10 different applications or web-based tools. I work on a 13" MB Pro without an external monitor, and typically I use the touch pad's app exposé function to quickly switch between windows. Most of the applications have a characteristic look, so my brain is usually pretty quick to identify the particular window that I need. Lately, however, both as a result of some uniformity trends in web and application design as well as the particular set of tools my latest job requires, all the windows look the same and it's hard to distinguish applications in exposé.

GitHub? White screen, black bar on top. AWS console? White screen, black bar on top. Outlook? White screen, black bar. Postman, Jenkins, various StackExchange sites? You see where I'm going with this... App exposé basically shows a lot of very similar looking windows. A few of these allow theming, but it requires that you have full control over the application or web site, so it's not always an option.

My question now: is there a way in Mac OS to customize the window title bar color on a per-window basis to make them look more distinct? Are there some other visual customization utilities available? (I noticed, e.g., that Microsoft Teams is able to put a colored frame around a window that's shared with the team).

Comment: I'd look into using Spaces more, rather than Exposé. Numbered screens, known apps on each. See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/179376/what-is-an-efficient-way-for-developers-power-users-to-use-osx-window-manageme and 
https://superuser.com/questions/1187532/macos-sierra-full-screen-multi-desktop-with-menu-bar for some ideas.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. You could disable SIP and edit the System's CAR files with [ThemeEngine](https://github.com/alexzielenski/ThemeEngine), but this isn't recommended, since you could destroy your Mac's UI.