# Selecting app icon in app switcher (w/ alt+tab) doesn't show its window if the app is on different workspace in macos catalina

Tags: applications, catalina, window-manager, mission-control

Whenever an app icon is selected in app switcher (triggered by alt+tab) its window does not show in macOS Catalina if the app is on a different workspace. When the icon is selected, nothing happens and I have to move to click control+left to switch to it. This issue doesn't happen for all apps, just for ones which are on different workspace. The app is on a different workspace because it's in full-screen mode. If minimized or maximized, selecting it in alt+tab shows it.

How to disable:

- moving to different workspace when app window is in-full screen (or better to disable workspaces and desktops at all)
- configuration which doesn't show the app window when it's selected in task switcher (alt+tab)

I've gone over settings and various articles, but couldn't find relevant configurations.

Off topic: This feature or bug seem to be extremely irritating for fast developer work as these basic features of window management work in Windows and Linux in intuitive and simple way...

Comment: Do you mean maximised or do you mean fullscreen - there's a distinct difference.

Comment: yes, it was full screen. When it's maximized the issue is gone, thanks a lot! 
edited my answer, i still want to disable all these defaults... they slow down fluent work....

Comment: tbh, I've avoided fullscreen since it was introduced. It's nothing but a disturbance to any workflow imo. Couple of links to examples of my own preferred workflow, which even gets rid of any reliance on Cmd/Tab & goes directly to the app you want - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/179376/what-is-an-efficient-way-for-developers-power-users-to-use-osx-window-manageme and
https://superuser.com/questions/1187532/macos-sierra-full-screen-multi-desktop-with-menu-bar

Comment: i'll go over them. you helped me greatly!

Comment: Most welcome :) I'm not certain your question can be answered more directly, but leave it open here in case others may find it in future & either provide a good solution themselves or follow through to my 'left field' alternative.