# Shortcut to switch between Spaces - and not Desktops

Tags: shortcut, mission-control

In Big Sur, using Mission Control we have the Control+1, Control+2 keyboard shortcuts to switch between **desktops**.

Is there a way (built-in is preferred of course) to switch to a specific **space** (including full-screen apps and not only desktops) by its number?

Comment: Spaces **are** Desktops. Apple unfortunately uses the two terms without differentiation. There is no way to switch to a specific fullscreen Space, because they don't have numbers.

Comment: I've done a couple of previous answers on how to make the most of Spaces - unfortunately any 'best use' method which involves Spaces also precludes the use of fullscreen. They just were never properly thought out when fullscreen was added to the existing Spaces philosophy & no-one has ever thought to go back & fix it. https://superuser.com/a/1187552/347380 and https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/179403/85275

Comment: @maybe by programming some dedicated automation? Tetsujin

Comment: Spaces is not scriptable. This page has a list of 3rd party Mac window managers which may be useful. I haven't tested any of them - https://www.slant.co/topics/526/~best-window-manager-for-mac

Comment: @Tetsujin but keyboard shortcuts are scriptable? so maybe it's possibe to levarage the Option+Left and Option+Right shortcuts of spaces, to mimic the Option+1 Option+2 of desktops by scripting

Comment: What are you hoping to gain? Sure you can script ctrl/1, 2 etc, but fullscreen spaces have no numbers, nor do they stay in any fixed order, so you'd need to script Ctrl/[last numbered space] then ctrl/right arrow enough times to reach correct the fullscreen space.

Comment: @Tetsujin Yes that's the flow i talked on. But, what do you mean by "nor do they stay in any fixed order"? what is the ordering logic?

Comment: Each new one goes to the right of all others. Order is then also dictated by the 'Automatically rearrange Spaces based on recent use" pref.

Comment: At the end I used Keyboard Mastro to assign specific keyboard shortcuts to switch to the few applications I use in fullscreen mode.

Comment: @nohillside - good call. Personally I dismissed fullscreen mode as useless within the first day it arrived to macOS & haven't touched it since ;))