# Is there a config option to maximize widows that are minimized when you select them via cmd+tab

Tags: window-manager

Is there a config option so maximize widows that are minimized when you select them via cmd+tab?

I understand why this might be not possible, since technically the selection involves the app, not the window. And you might have multiple windows in various states of maximized/minimized. And you don't necessarily want to maximize all minimized windows...

BUT, that said, I often just have one minimized window of an app open, and it would be very useful for it to maximize itself when I select the app with cmd+tab.

Thoughts?

Comment: I don't minimize stuff so it doesn't make sense to me. You are just adding extra work for no reason. You can use hide (command+h) if you really need to get rid of the app for a while. Or else you may use that weird "spaces" feature, which is annoying but maybe useful.

Comment: Cmd-Tab is an application switcher, not a window switcher.

Comment: @MateusRibeiro - That *'weird "spaces" feature'* is one of the most useful things Apple ever devised. It's just a shame they spoiled it when they added fullscreen. See https://superuser.com/a/1187552/347380 and https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/179403/85275

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not certain that this addresses the problem but still: after you <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⇥</kbd> to desired application then without releasing <kbd>⌘</kbd> press <kbd>↓</kbd> (down arrow) or <kbd>↑</kbd> (up arrow). This will display all windows of this application. Those which are minimized are displayed in smaller size. You can navigate to desired window using arrow keys and then press <kbd>⏎</kbd> to bring it up.

Comment: This is pretty awesome. Might be the closest to what I need!