# How to command+tab on the current window?

Tags: macos

I have started using a mac for my daily work and one thing I cannot figure out is how to make the command+tab window appear on my current monitor when working with more than one monitor.

As soon as I hit command+tab I end up seeing the list on the main monitor not where my mouse is located. Is there a way to change this behaviour?

Comment: Have you considered an alternative method of switching apps. Cmd/Tab is a bit… ermm… 1990s ;)) It's a sawn-off shotgun vs a sniper rifle. I'd consider using Spaces, with one [or related] apps on each Space, then you can just flip to the one you need by number. See https://superuser.com/a/1187552/347380 and https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/179403/85275 for some tips.

Comment: If you don't mind App Switcher showing up on both/all monitors then you can use this solution: https://superuser.com/a/1625752/1257149

Comment: Thank you both for your comments, I guess the answer to my question is no. But then I think I can live with either option you presented.