# How to assign application window to a specific hotkey on a MacOS?

Tags: macos, big-sur

For example: safari is always `command + 1` 
chrome is always `command + 2` 
terminal is always `command + 3` etc 
Window arrangement **should not influence** hotkey combination. It also would be great if I could use windows in full screen mode. 
So far I have tried Witch and Amethyst applications. I didn't succeed setting them up as described earlier.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Spaces will do this. See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/179376/what-is-an-efficient-way-for-developers-power-users-to-use-osx-window-manageme and 
https://superuser.com/questions/1187532/macos-sierra-full-screen-multi-desktop-with-menu-bar

Comment: This can also be solved with a workflow in Alfred ("Hotkey" trigger, "Launch Apps/Files" action; target would be the app's path, which brings it into foreground if it's already running). But using Spaces and pinning each app to a specific space is a good solution and what I'm actually doing.

Comment: @Tetsujin As far as I understand I can not use windows full screen, can I?

Comment: Please *edit* the question to add the things you've tried, make sure to also mention additional constraints like wanting to use this with applications in full screen mode.

Comment: Fullscreen breaks the association between Space number & assigned app [yet another of the very many reasons I refuse to have anything to do with fullscreen]. Just hide the menu bar instead if you want that bit more room at the top.