# Exclude certain app from mission control

Tags: window-manager, mission-control

I have several apps open and few of them I don't want to be in mission control, I never need to select them but I do need them open (I access functionalities via shortcuts)

is it possible to exclude them? My mission control screening is getting messier because of the many apps I load.

Comment: Have you considered using Spaces instead of opening everything in one Space? Mission Control will show all apps in the current Space, there's no way round that. See https://superuser.com/a/1187552/347380 and https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/179403/85275 for some examples.

Comment: Thanks! Very new to Mac world. I'll setup my spaces :)

Comment: Welcome. If you struggle or have any issues setting it up feel free to ask further questions in Ask Different. Let me put that into an answer, just in case anyone else searches the same question…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered using Spaces instead of opening everything in one Space?

Mission Control will show all apps in the current Space, there's no way round that.
See [What is an efficient way for developers / power users to use OSX window management and Spaces on a single screen?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/179376/what-is-an-efficient-way-for-developers-power-users-to-use-osx-window-manageme/179403#179403)
and on our sister site Super User - [MacOS Sierra - Full screen/multi desktop WITH menu bar](https://superuser.com/questions/1187532/macos-sierra-full-screen-multi-desktop-with-menu-bar/1187552#1187552) for some examples.