# Hide minimized or hidden windows in app switcher

Tags: macos, applications, windows

I'm new to MacOs and something drives me nuts. When I minimize(command + w) or hide(command + h) a window, this window will still be selectable in the app switcher (command + tab). Is there any solution to get this window be hidden in the switcher?

Comment: This is a good question but I would ask if you got this working how would you open a hidden window?

Comment: What's your workflow, that needs this? I often find people coming from other OSes are so used to swapping between process by [something]/Tab that they fail to see the other, smarter, alternatives Mac has to offer - like putting apps in different Spaces & being able to go directly to any numbered Space by key command… or using Mission Control to expose all apps in a single view.

Comment: Thanks for your quick responses. In my 'active' apps I'm using the fullscreen mode (control + command + f), so that I have only one regular workspace (Desktop 1) for finder etc and several 'app-workspaces'. To navigate quickly between these workspaces I'm using the app switcher. My desired behaviour is to run minimized apps like a daemon, so that I can receive notifications from theses minimized apps (eg Mail and Slack), but without being able to select these in the app switcher. if you know another keyboard-driven workflow that includes fullscreen windows please let me know.

Comment: Yeah… amongst the many reasons I avoid fullscreen like the plague is the screens aren't numbered, so can't be key commanded. This as far as I'm concerned, breaks any sensible workflow.

Comment: Have a look at https://superuser.com/a/1187552/347380 and https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/179403/85275 for alternative working methods, using Spaces