# The simplest way to minimize a window just for a moment?

Tags: mac, window-manager

Let's say I have mydoc.pdf displayed on screen (in Skim) and I minimize it just for a moment to access some other document or app. When I click on Skim icon in the dock to display mydoc.pdf back, inevitably it opens some other pdf document minimized much earlier instead (because usually I have multiple pdfs minimized in Skim). Is there any way to fix it?

What is the "right" way of doing it? Not minimizing any apps and using cmd-tab or the dock to access another program when needed? (I find keeping all windows open messy, but it just me.)

Comment: Use tabbed documents. [idk Skim, but most apps can do that these days]. That way, all your docs are available like in a web browser - just click the appropriate tab. Alternatively, investigate SPaces, so you can have one app on each Space [that doesn't work so well for multiple docs in multiple Spaces, but it saves you ever having to use Cmd/Tab ever again. See https://superuser.com/a/1187552/347380 and https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/179403/85275 for some ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hide the app instead of minimizing.

While in Skim, press `⌘+h` on the keyboard.  This hides all non-minimized windows of the active application.  When you go back (`⌘+Tab` or clicking in the dock) it returns to where you were last.
FWIW - You can get here the long way by clicking the Skim menu from the menu bar, next to the  menu, and choose "Hide Skim".

Additionally, if you just want to jump to the desktop very quickly you can leverage gestures by "Spread with thumb and three fingers" on the trackpad.  Check you system preferences to enable this (See this Apple Support Document for more info [Use Multi-Touch gestures on your Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204895)).

Both of the above solutions become habitual muscle memory very quickly.

Comment: You can also opt/click onto another app, which will hide the app you're leaving.