# Is there an app to manage multiple "Desktop Spaces" (not monitors)?

Tags: desktop, spaces

I like to use the Desktop Spaces feature when working on a single monitor as it allows me to have, for example, InDesign running in one Desktop Space, my writing app in another, and the remainder of my apps in a third. I can then do a four-finger swipe on my trackpad to switch between the Desktop Spaces.

I have looked around to find a Desktop Spaces manager that will allow me to automatically assign different apps to different spaces, but cannot find anything.

Does anyone know if such a utility exists?

Comment: See https://superuser.com/a/1187552/347380 and https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/179403/85275

Answer (score 1):

Does this help: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250846933

Right click the icon in the dock, then go to the Options menu. There's an "Assign to..." option to let the app appear on all desktops or only "this" desktop.

I think that's what you wanted.