# When using OS X terminal open command, e.g. `open .`, how can I control which screen/desktop the Finder window opens on?

Tags: terminal, finder, desktop

I use a TV as a large external monitor & typically have a few OS X Desktops on the external screen for browsers, code editors, etc., along with 2 or 3 Desktops open on my MacBook Pro screen, w/ one always being Terminal, full-screen. Lately, when I want to open the current directory from Terminal, `open .` opens it above the full-screen terminal window. Is there any way to control where the window will open in terms of screen/desktop? I have included my configuration below. The Finder windows are showing up over the full-screen terminal session, instead of Desktop 1 where I want them

Desktop configuration, external monitor

> ```
> Desktop 3  |  Desktop 4  |  Desktop 5   |   Desktop 6
> ```

Desktop configuration, builtin screen

> ```
>   Terminal  |  Desktop 1  |  Desktop 2
> ```

Comment: See https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/179403/85275
 and https://superuser.com/a/1187552/347380 idk how a new window can even open over a fullscreen Space. I thought that was not possible. Fullscreen Spaces also generate to the right of all numbered Spaces - unless you manually drag it into place from Mission Control.

Comment: @Tetsujin thanks, I'll check out those links. I think the issue may have started when I had the external monitor disconnected, but it kept up the same behaviour until I restarted it today - currently seems resolved