# How to minimize all open windows when using Firefox?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut, window-manager

If I try to use <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Opt</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> combination it opens mobile viewing in Firefox.

And if I click somewhere on the desktop and press <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Opt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> then the Finder remains open.

Is there a way to force everything to minimize?
Thanks. This is the first time I'm using Mac.

Comment: Rather than use the clumsy Windows-style minimise/maximise to unclutter your desktop, I'd have a look at how to use Spaces instead. See https://superuser.com/a/1187552/347380 and https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/179403/85275 for some pointers.

Answer (score 2):

Click on the Dock icon while holding down the <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Opt</kbd> keys.

Comment: What is the Dock icon?

Comment: In Windows, this is called the taskbar. I think it makes sense that you are reading [this](https://www.imore.com/how-use-dock-your-mac).

Comment: I figured it out, if you slide your finger across the touch pad to the left it works