# How do i open minimized window on current mac spaces?

Tags: macos, terminal, spaces

So, I want to open my minimized terminal on the Mozilla space but whenever I open my terminal, it opens on the Finder space. How can I make it to open on the Mozilla workspace?

Answer (score 1):

It will open on the Space it was minimised on, unless the app affinity is set to "All Desktops"

[image]

If Mozilla is in fullscreen, then this will not work.

For much more on use of Spaces, see
https://superuser.com/a/1187552/347380 and https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/179403/85275