# How to create a keyboard macro for cycling through applications, on Kinetic Advantage360 keyboard

Tags: keyboard, applescript

I own a Kinetic Advantage360 keyboard with macro recording capabilities.  This allows me to create sequences of key presses bound to the keyboard's special macro keys.

My goal is to create a keyboard macro that enables me to switch to the *next* application, similar to holding down <kbd>Command</kbd> and repeatedly pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd>. Unfortunately, I haven't figured out how to achieve this with my keyboard. I'm exploring the possibility of using the Kinetic Advantage360 keyboard's macro capabilities or AppleScript (or whatever other automation facility may be in vogue nowadays). However, my knowledge of the latter is quite limited.

I have found no ordinary shortcut in macOS for switching to the next application that I could use.

Any helpful input would be greatly welcomed.

I'm on macOS Ventura, 13.5.1 (Mac Mini, M1).

Comment: See https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/179403/85275 and https://superuser.com/a/1187552/347380