# Shortcut to escape from "Space" to main screen

Tags: desktop, spaces, mission-control

Using terminology from [Work in multiple spaces on Mac](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/work-in-multiple-spaces-mh14112/mac#:%7E:text=Create%20a%20space,create%20up%20to%2016%20spaces.), spaces are additional desktops.

Let's say I have five spaces open and I am on the right-most one. Is there a shortcut I can use to go to the left-most space aka "Desktop 1"?

What I've tried:

- When I look in **Settings > Desktop & Dock** I see **Shortcuts** including "Show Desktop" but that just minimizes all windows and shows the desktop as opposed to the left-most space you'd see in mission control.
- I know I can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd> / <kbd>→</kbd> to quickly navigate between spaces but hoping for a quicker shortcut to take me straight to the left-most space.

For context, I am on a laptop and one monitor setup, with the monitor as my main display and my laptop as my extended display.

Comment: Also see https://superuser.com/a/1187552/347380 and https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/179403/85275 for some additional Spaces tips & tricks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that these instructions are for macOS 13.x, I do not know if they are different for other versions.

Navigate to Settings > Keyboard and in the second 'box'  for "Keyboard Navigation" click the "Keyboard Shortcuts ..." button.

[image]

In the resultant popup click on "Mission Control" in the left sidebar.

Then in the right panel look for the "Mission Control" item with the 'flipply triangle', ">" and click on the ">" to expand the set of options.

Enable the "Switch to Desktop1" item by clicking the checkbox. This will enable the shortcut ⌃1 , (control 1), which will jump you to Desktop 1, which should be the leftmost space.

[image]

Then click the "Done" button.

Comment: Nice you can customize key combination too. That's perfect, thank you @SteveM!!